# how to use the InputSupplier or OutputSupplier api of Guava?

Tags: java, io, guava

I am new to the guava library, and I am quite confused with the InputSupplier and OutputSupplier. According to the javadoc, they are just factories for InputStream and OutputStream respectively. However, I don't see anything quite useful of these two interface, could anyone show me a example why I should use these two APIs besides for higher abstraction?

Answer (score 31):

The main benefit of both of these interfaces is that they allow library code to control the whole lifecycle of the actual input/output objects. Guava's utilities never close an `InputStream` or `OutputStream` that you pass in directly, because that might not be what you want to happen. Even if they did, you'd still need `try`/`finally` to deal with errors creating objects. The suppliers are a sort of lazy callback that allow the actual objects to be created, used and closed all in one go without you having to do a lot of ugly `try`/`finally` and error handling.

For an example, just look at the code it takes to copy one file to another (with the actual copying and stream closing code minimized using Guava utilities):

```
File in = ...
File out = ...
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(in);
boolean threw = true;
try {
  /*
   * Note how two try/finally blocks are needed here, in case creating 
   * outStream fails.
   */
  FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(out);
  try {
    ByteStreams.copy(inStream, outStream);
    threw = false;
  } finally {
    Closeables.close(outStream, threw);
  }
} finally {
  Closeables.close(inStream, threw);
}
```

Then look at the code if you use suppliers instead:

```
File in = ...
File out = ...
ByteStreams.copy(Files.newInputStreamSupplier(in), 
    Files.newOutputStreamSupplier(out));
```

Comment: +1 . I like how you explain it, using the "lifecycle" concept. I hadn't thought about the fact that Guava only closes these resources when it controls the whole lifecycle. Makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I really like your answer

Comment: Some of these advantages are mitigated in Java 7 with the try-with-resources syntax, but `c.g.c.io` will probably need a complete Java 7 redesign anyway.

Comment: Amen to that. We had to make our own utility methods to create InputSuppliers for the various other things (like Path) which their API is missing.

Answer (score 4):

With Guava's InputSupplier / OutputSupplier, you do not have to handle yourself the various IOExceptions thrown when instantiating FileInputStreams / FileOutputStreams. Guava will automatically handle these exceptions for you when it calls the InputSupplier.getInput() / OutputSupplier.getOutput() factory methods.

By encapsulating the input / output construction in these factory interfaces, you *defer* their instantiation, and thus defer the moment you will need to handle the IOException / FileNotFoundException they may throw. In fact, you defer it so much, that it's Guava that handles it for you.

You can then replace

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    doSomething(inputStream);
```

with

```
    InputSupplier<FileInputStream> inputStreamSupplier = Files.newInputStreamSupplier(file);

    doSomething(inputStreamSupplier);
```

Edit: also see ColinD's answer, on how Guava may close these inputs / outputs for you when it controls their whole lifecycle (that is, when it used an InputSupplier / OutputSupplier to obtain them).

Comment: +1 for using generics in your example.  The only thing I might add to the example code is to show that when you call the getInput method on the inputStreamSupplier, you only have to catch IOException.  I also found this the common java cookbook (avaliable at (http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/guava-io-sect-flush-close.html) useful.